# MySQL database using xampplite

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed xampplite on windows 10.But when i try to open MySQL database by opening my browser and entering http://localhost/phpmyadmin ,it just opens an empty page with just a Share hyperlink on top left of the page...How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea of xampplite tbh. i use the plain xampp. You need to launch mysql and apache first. Have you done that?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling it and installing the normal xampp again?

Comment: Okay will try doing that...Thanks

Comment: See if this link helps you in any way http://support.ongetc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=293